# Como dirigirme a una carpeta en especifico en CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Dejo una captura de como tengo la estructura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente estoy en la View del Folder inicio, pero quiero redirigirme a la carpeta recaudación.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>recaudacion">Descarga</a>
```

Pero no me muestra nada. Como puedo acceder al controlador por defecto de la carpeta Recaudacion??? Dentro de Routes cada carpeta tiene su controlador por defecto.

Este es mi **`index.php`** que esta en la raíz del proyecto:

```
//recaudacion.php
$application_folder = 'application/recaudacion';

//inicio.php
$application_folder = 'application/inicio';
```

Agradezco ayuda, muchas gracias!

> **EDIT:** Todavía no lo pude resolver, existe esta posibilidad de poner dos carpetas dentro de application ????

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que se está refiriendo dentro de su aplicación.

Puede crear su propia  etiqueta e insertar una URL en el href como esta

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/uri') ?>">Link</a>
```

O puede usar el asistente de URL de esta manera para generar una etiqueta

```
anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)
```

Entonces ... para usarlo ...

```
<?php echo anchor('controller/function/uri', 'Link', 'class="link-class"') ?>
```

y eso generará

```
<a href="http://domain.com/index.php/controller/function/uri" class="link-class">Link</a>
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>img/path/file.jpg" /></a>
```